# How to remove text in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, cmd

I want to make a CMD command by vb, if `textbox1.text` contains CMD then it remove "CMD " and it take the rest of text and (Call shell) of it

example:( CMD SHUTDOWN -t 15 ), then it delete "CMD " and it take "SHUTDOWN -t 15" to (Call Shell) to it

this is my code... and of course it's not working :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 If TextBox1.Text.Contains("CMD") = True Then
  TextBox1.Text.Remove("CMD ")
  Call Shell(TextBox1.Text)
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: In which sub (and when) are you calling this code?

Comment: no error, it's just not working, it shows visual studio codes with a yellow ribbon on it

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains("CMD ") = True Then 
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("CMD ","") 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
... 
TexBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("CMD ", "") 
Shell(TextBox1.Text)
```

1) Remove has no overload that takes a sub-string, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, hence my use of replace here.

2) No need to use the call keyword here.

3) Just a heads up, but:

```
if TextBox1.Text.Contains("CMD") = True
```

is the same as:

```
if TextBox1.Text.Contains("CMD")
```

Comment: okay, it worked in replacing text, but cmd not taking any commands.
and it writes :-
Microsoft Windows [version 6.3.9600]
<c>2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reseved.

C:\ :the location path of my project: >

Comment: What was the string passed to Shell()? Works fine on my end tested with "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe".

Comment: Worth noting that running `TextBox1.Text.Replace` will not actually do the replacement, in only returns new string, where replacement has been made.

Comment: Yup, my mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

To start CMD with parameters try:

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -f -t 30")
```

This force-shuts down the computer in 30 seconds.

The text between the second pair of quotation marks are the parameters, which in your case would be '-t 15'.